# Do I need to reinstall R-Studio if I wish to use Anaconda with R?

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

I have R (version 3.5.0) installed along with R-Studio (version 1.1.453). I recently installed Anaconda. In order to use Anaconda with R, do I need to reinstall R-Studio? I don't see an option for R notebooks when I launch Jupyter. However, there is an option to install R-Studio in the Anaconda Navigator.

Also, the option for installing R-Studio through the Anaconda Navigator suggests that the version of R-Studio that will be installed will be older than that already installed. Will there be a conflict between the two versions of R-Studio if I select this option?

Comment: Anaconda ships with it's own distribution for R, from Microsoft I believe. So there are already two installations of R on your computer.  For using R insiide jupyter notebooks, you need to install the IRkernel with `conda install -c r r-irkernel` in a terminal window. Note that this new isntallation of R won't have any of your previously installed libraries on it

Comment: R != RStudio. RStudio and Jupyter are IDEs for using the R binary. To run an R kernel in Jupyter, see [the docs](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/).

Comment: I was able to successfully install irkernel using the step mentioned in the link provided above. However, when I try to make the kernel available to Jupyter, I get the following error:                                                                                                           Error in IRkernel::installspec() : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("jupyter", c("kernelspec", "--version"), FALSE, FALSE) :
  '"jupyter"' not found

Comment: I would still recommend using Rstudio as standalone because it makes R's package management much more efficient and less conflict prone. With Anaconda, you have the plus point that you have a full data science suite, but I've heard that R's package management through conda is more tedious and conflict prone. Its always good to have Python and R as separate installations.

Comment: The RStudio version with Anaconda is 1.1.453 but RStudio's current version is 1.3.595 the issue arises with VSCode also.  I haven't found a use case for keeping them together.  It seems Anaconda uses this as an advertising gimmick.  Having RStudio for R, Anaconda for Python, and VSCode for all else and separate seems to work best for me.  Perhaps you want Jupyter Labs, Jupyter Notebooks, Rmarkdown files to write up nice reports.   There is a natural connection between python, R, and julia which is good enough without requiring them to be in the same IDE.  Development teams work best alone.

Answer (score 2):

Use R kernel with Jupyter in Anaconda only need install:

```
conda install r-essentials
```